# Space ending in rootfs

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora, disk-space

My problem is that I think in a couple of days there will be no space free in rootfs.

Is is possible somehow to 'clear' rootfs from unnecessary files? What should I look for?

Rootfs is mounted into md123 RAID1.

In general I have following FS division at my system:

```
[root@host/]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                2.8G  2.6G   75M  98% /
udev                  1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 1.5G  444K  1.5G   1% /run
/dev/md123            2.8G  2.6G   75M  98% /
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /media
/dev/md124            772M   36M  697M   5% /boot
/dev/md122            184G   61G  114G  35% /home
/dev/md126            7.4G  1.9G  5.1G  28% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/md120            1.9G  134M  1.7G   8% /tmp
/dev/md121            276G  139G  123G  53% /home2
/dev/md125             20G  8.3G   11G  46% /h1
/dev/md119            2.7T  480G  2.1T  19% /backup
```

[image: output from munin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to find the files which are growing and then check if you still need them or not. Usually the first place to look at it `/var/log`, because all the log files are there and likely to grow.

One thing which for me is usually very useful is the `du` command's --max-depth parameter. because that way i can just compare all subdirectories of one directory. For example if you want to see the sizes of all subdirectories of `/var/log` compared with each other. You can do the following:

```
cd /var/log
du -h --max-depth=1
```

that way it sums up the size of the files in all subdirectories and lists the total for each subdirectory.

furthermore, `ls -lhaS` is also very useful. it lists all files of the current directory, and sorts them by size. So for example you can also check that:

```
cd /var/log
ls -lhaS | more
```

to see the biggest files inside `/var/log`

btw. 2.8G is quite small for a root partition. It's easy to fill that by accident if you don't monitor your services closely.

Comment: yup currently looking for 'space consumer' with du. unfortunately this would be quite problematic to change something atm.

Comment: You mean it would be hard to grow the size of the root partition? Well, thats often the case, unless the root partition was on something dynamic like LVM from the beginning. But growing the partition is a completely different topic.

Comment: yup this is very-very small server, and the partitioning was made long ago before I took it under my supervision, so this is not the only one problem with partitioning here %). Also I found out with du what in var folder most space consumers are `cache`, `spool` and `log` directories - `500MB`.

Comment: Then i think you should check for each of them if you need to keep them, and otherwise remove. For example in the log folder you might not need a lot of stuff which is still there. Possibly you could prevent this issue in the future by changing the logrotate settings to keep the logfolder small. for `cache` and `spool` it depends heavily on the services you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `du -x --max-depth=1 / | sort -nr` to get an idea of what top-level folders in the partition are taking up the most space, then start descending though the folders until you find your space-hogs.

`/var/log` is a usual suspect, like mauro mentioned, but `/usr` and `/var` themselves can also be subject to some bloat. I usually create a separate `/usr` partition and copy/symlink `/var` into it.